R adding label to dataframe column mess up the order()?
The method="radix" makes difference when applying to the data frame below, as shown in df1 (COVID first) and df2 (Constipation first). But after I added a label to the column, it doesn't matter anymore, Constipation always show up first. Why adding label changes the way order() function work?
Thanks
KB
df <- data.frame(name=c("COVID","Constipation"),loc=c("USA","GBR"))
df1 <- df[order(df$name,method="radix"),]
df1
          name loc
1        COVID USA
2 Constipation GBR
df2 <- df[order(df$name),]
df2
          name loc
2 Constipation GBR
1        COVID USA

label(df$name) <- "Name of the disease"
df1 <- df[order(df$name,method="radix"),]
df1
          name loc
2 Constipation GBR
1        COVID USA
df2 <- df[order(df$name),]
df2
          name loc
2 Constipation GBR
1        COVID USA


Where does the function label() come from? Please include libraries of any non-base package you're using.

It looks like label is Hmisc::label - i can replicate the issue.

Yes, label from Hmisc

order(c("Co","CO"), method="radix") is c(2,1) versus order(Hmisc::\label<-`(c("Co","CO"), value="Name"), method="radix")isc(1,2)`.
